# Scale-invariant OpenCV image template matching in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, sift, template-matching

The method [`cv2.matchTemplate`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) gives a translation-invariant template matching on an image, but not scale-invariant.

**How to do a scale-invariant (or even rotation-invariant) template matching with Open CV for Python?**

Is there a way to use a log-polar FFT template matcher built-in in OpenCV for Python?

([here](https://github.com/Smorodov/LogPolarFFTTemplateMatcher) is a C++ version)

Note:

- I'd like to avoid the "simple trick"  of matching many times in loop with scaled versions of the same template, as shown in [Multi-scale Template Matching using Python and OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/)
- Related: https://answers.opencv.org/question/169613/how-does-macthtemplate-deal-with-scali
- https://pypi.org/project/imreg/ is related but no longer developed and with no documentation

Comment: See https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.730.9105&rep=rep1&type=pdf and https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/registration/plot_register_rotation.html

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you for the links. For the second, do you have a code example about how it can be applied to a template matching context? For the first, is there a code sample repo somewhere?

Comment: feature matching is popular...

Comment: @Basj.  Sorry, no other examples for either link. I tried coding to extend the second and got one example to work, but it failed on another.